# Cannot 301.htaccess redirect in XAMPP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

A simple working 301 .htaccess redirect on my live server looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

redirect 301 /test.php /index.php
```

But I can't make it work my XAMPP installation.
I have enabled mod_rewrite.so in the http.conf file and I can't see why it does not redirect.  Have restarted apache but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know that Apache's `redirect` directive is from mod_alias module not from more_rewrite module. Check docs here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

If you want to handle it via mod_rewrite it then use it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test\.php$ /index.php [L,NC,R=301]
```

ALternatively enable mod_alias module to make `redirect` work.

Comment: Thanks - the code does work, but there is an issue I didn't mention!

Works fine live, but locally, index.php takes me back to DocumentRoot and not to the home page of the site.  It works if I change index.php to "/home/sitefolder/public_html/index.php", but then that doesn't work live.

I want to use the same .htaccess file for local and live servers.

Comment: On local server what is your DocumentRoot and why is it different from your site's home page?

Comment: DocumentRoot on XAMPP is "E:/" which is obviously different from the live server.  The question is why does my original code [redirect 301 /test.php /index.php] work perfectly on live web, but fails locally.  What would I need to tweak to get it to work in XAMPP?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by creating a local domain Using [Apache Virtual Hosts](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts#zfbook.creating.a.local.domain.using.apache.virtual.hosts.conclusion).  Once the local domain is setup, the redirect code works as it does on the live server:

```
redirect 301 /test.php /test2.php.php
```